# Fourier transform in the exponent with a multiplication operator

Tags: quantum-mechanics, operators, fourier-transform

I am going through Dr Frederic Schuller's course on Quantum Theory. In the 19th Lecture on The Schrodinger Operator, where F is a Fourier Transform and P squared is maximally defined real multiplication operator, the derivation goes like this:

[image]

I can't find a way to prove this.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: You don't know how to go from the first equation to the second, or how to even arrive at the first equation?

Comment: I know how to get to the first one. Thanks for replying.

Answer (score 0):

Going from your first expression to the second is just a matter of multiplying by $-it$ and exponentiating both sides
$$
e^{-it\mathfrak{F}^{-1}P^2\mathfrak{F}} = e^{-itH_\text{free}}
$$
Now we must notice that in an exponential, leftmost- and rightmost-pairs of operators $A$ and their inverse $A^{-1}$ can be pulled out of the exponential as in
$$
e^{A^{-1}B A} = \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{(A^{-1}B A)^k}{k!} = A^{-1} \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{B^k}{k!}A = A^{-1} e^{B} A
$$
because the in-between pairs of $A^{-1}$ and $A$ cancel out like
$$
(A^{-1}B A)^k = A^{-1}B \underbrace{A A^{-1}}_{=\mathbb{1}} B \ldots B A = A^{-1} B^k A
$$
where we used the definition of the exponential function as a Taylor series.

So we have
$$
\mathfrak{F}^{-1} e^{-itP^2}\mathfrak{F} = e^{-itH_\text{free}}
$$
where we only need to multiply by $\mathfrak{F}^{-1}$ from the right to get
$$
\mathfrak{F}^{-1} e^{-itP^2} = e^{-itH_\text{free}}\mathfrak{F}^{-1} \quad\square
$$

Comment: I think that you can't use Taylor series here. You have to define the exponential of an operator as a Lebesgue integral and use the projection valued measure associated with the self-adjoint operator.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I'll try to use integrals instead of sums.

Comment: An exponential of an operator is defined by its Taylor series, so this is just substituting the shorthand $e^A$ with its actual definition of a sum.

Comment: You're right in case of a certain class of an operator, but these are self-adjoint operators on the infinite dimesional Hilbert space of Lebesgue square integrable functions. So the Taylor series makes no sense.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not used to taking $\mathfrak{F}$ as a Fourier Transform ``operator'', but this sounds interesting. If I were to treat it as I would any other operator, then I would probably prove the relation you have as follows:

1. Begin by showing that your relation implies that for any integer $n$: $$\mathfrak{F}^{-1}P^{2n}\mathfrak{F} = H_\text{free}^n.\tag{1} \label{1}$$
2. Now, the exponential of some operator $\hat{O}$ is *defined* using its power series expansion: $$e^{\hat{O}}\equiv \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{\hat{O}^n}{n!},$$ and so you should be able to multiply Equation (\ref{1}) with the appropriate constants and sum over all values of $n$ to get:

\begin{aligned}
\sum_{n=0}^\infty\mathfrak{F}^{-1} \frac{(-it P )^n}{n!}\,\, \mathfrak{F}\quad &= \quad\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{(- i t H_\text{free})^n}{n!},\\
\implies \mathfrak{F}^{-1}  \Bigg(\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{(-it P )^n}{n!}\Bigg) \mathfrak{F} \quad &= \quad\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{(- i t H_\text{free})^n}{n!}
\end{aligned}

3. From here, you should be able to use the definition of the exponential of an operator given above, and multiply the last equation by $\mathfrak{F}^{-1}$ on the right to get: $$\mathfrak{F}^{-1} e^{-it P^2} = e^{-i t H_\text{free}}\mathfrak{F}^{-1}.$$

Comment: I think you have to use Lebesgue integration and the projection valued measure instead of the power series expansion though.